# Save the timestamp of the most recently created csv file within a directory to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch files and would like to get the timestamp of the latest created file of certain type within a folder, and store that timestamp within a variable.

So far this is what I have:

```
FOR /f %%i in ('dir /O:D /T:C /b *.csv') DO (set LAST=%%i
    goto stop)

:stop

echo Last created file:%LAST%
```

The output is the file name but I need the timestamp too.

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type `FOR /?` Read the last section about the command modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
::@echo off
set LAST=
set TimeStamp=
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,4" %%i in ('dir /O:-D /T:C *.csv^|findstr .csv') DO (
    set "LAST=%%k"
    set "TimeStamp=%%i %%j"
    goto stopfor
)
:stopfor

echo Last created file: %LAST%
echo Time Stamp: %TimeStamp%
```

`-` before `D` is for descending order.
Removed `-b` because it will suppress the timestamp from showing.
And then pipe to `findstr` to show only those file lines. (Ignore summaries)
Check `for /?`, `dir /?` and `findstr /?` for more.

Another way, no need to pipe to `findstr`:

```
::@echo off
set LAST=
set TimeStamp=
FOR /f  %%i in ('dir /O:-D /T:C /b *.csv') DO (
    set "LAST=%%i"
    set "TimeStamp=%%~ti"
    goto stopfor
)
:stopfor

echo Last created file: %LAST%
echo Time Stamp: %TimeStamp%
```

Comment: Works like a charm.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to add this as an alternative answer, for providing the created timestamp  including seconds, i.e `yyyy/MM/dd @hh:mm:ss`.
The method of determining the file has not been changed, `DIR`, I've just used the WMI command line utility `wmic.exe` to retrieve the date in a none locale dependent way.

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist *.csv Exit/B
For /F Delims^=^= %%A In ('Set _ 2^>Nul')Do Set "%%A="
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/OD/TC *.csv 2^>Nul'
    )Do If /I "%%~xA"==".csv" Set "_F=%__CD__%%%A"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('WMIC DataFile Where "Name='%_F:\=\\%'"^
 Get CreationDate 2^>Nul')Do For %%B In (%%~nA)Do Set "_C=%%B"
If Not Defined _C Exit /B
Set "_C=%_C:~,4%/%_C:~4,2%/%_C:~6,2% @ %_C:~-6,2%:%_C:~-4,2%.%_C:~-2%"
If Defined _F Echo( Your latest file, %_F%, was created on %_C%&Pause
```

---

If you only need the timestamp as a variable you could use simpler looking methods.

You could leverage `powershell.exe` from your batch file, *which also allows for seconds accuracy*:

```ps1
@For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP^
 "Ls *.csv|Sort CreationTime|Select CreationTime" 2^>Nul'
)Do @Set "CTS=%%A"
@Set CTS 2>Nul&&Pause
```

*This version would be preferable if you have a large number of csv files in the current directory and will give you a method to control the `-F`ormat of the result)*:

```ps1
@For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP^
 "Ls . -Filt *.csv|Sort CreationTime -Des|Select -F 1 -Exp CreationTime|"^
 "Date -F 'yyyy/MM/dd @hh:mm:ss'" 2^>Nul')Do @Set "CTS=%%A"
@Set CTS 2>Nul&&Pause
```

Or, if you want to stick with `cmd.exe` only, you are satisfied that the date and time are always shown as the first and second space delimited strings of the `DIR` command and you don't need more than minute accuracy, then I'd suggest that you could use this:

```bat
@For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/OD/TC *.csv 2^>Nul'
    )Do @If /I "%%~xA"==".csv" For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ("%%A"
    )Do @Set "CTS=%%B @%%C"
@Set CTS 2>Nul&&Pause
```